# SharePoint Online - Sync two AAD into one SP User profile

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile, profile-sync, aad

***I am trying to synchronize all users from two different AAD under same tenant into one single User profile application.*** I know that this is not possible by writing any custom sync job as CSOM does not have any user profile creation API. Does the OOTB SharePoint user profile sync job support this? If not what are the alternatives I have here.